# Haskell - Instance of Num Char required for definition of a function

Tags: haskell

I want to write a simple recursive function with 3 input parameters and 1 output parameter:

```
getLengthOfNumber :: (String, Int, Int) -> Int
getLengthOfNumber (n, i, res)
    | isCharDigit(n!!i+1) = getLengthOfNumber (n, i+1, res+1)
    | otherwise = res
```

Why does Hugs throw me the Error "Instance of Num Char required for definition of getLengthOfNumber"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it interprets:

```
n!!i+1
```

as:

```
(n!!i) + 1
```

It thus first obtains the `i`-th character of the string, and then aims to add `1` to it. Now in Haskell one can define a custom number type. So here you *could* add that character and `1` together, but only if that character is a number.

But that being said, the above will not work even by fixing the brackets. You did not instruct when to *stop* iterating: for the string `"123"`, it would eventually obtain the last character, and then raise an "index too large" error when it reaches the end of the string. Furthermore `!!` is *not* efficient: it requires *O(k)* to access the *k*-th element, making this algorithm a quadratic one.

What you here can use is [**`takeWhile :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:takeWhile) and [**`length :: [a] -> Int`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:length): first take the longest prefix of character, and then take the length of that list, like:

```
getLengthOfNumber :: String -> Int
getLengthOfNumber = length . takeWhile isCharDigit
```

Comment: Thanks! n!!(i+1) fixed my problem. Apart from that, the function works just as I need it to.

Comment: @GeorgNatter: what if you input `"123"`?

Answer (score 3):

`!!` has higher priority than `+`, so `n!!i+1` is parsed as `(n !! i) + 1`, which tries to add one to an element of a string, which only works if `Char` is a number.  You should instead write `n !! (i+1)`.